# RXJava Update List

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, subscribe

I'm absolutely new to RxJava. I'm trying to "listen" to a list changes:

```
filteredEvents = eventViewModel.getAllByInterval(dateStart, dateEnd);

Disposable disposable = filteredEvents.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
                (events, throwable) -> {
                    if (throwable != null) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (events != null) {
                        // do funny things
                    }
                }
        );

compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
```

Now: what if I want to dinamically change filtered events, e.g. changing dateStart and dateEnd interval? Should i re-subscribe to the new list content? I'd like to reuse filteredEvents. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for `BehaviorRelay<Pair<Date, Date>>` and then `relay.switchMap { eventViewModel.getAllByInterval(first, second`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should just dispose of your current disposable, and create a new one. This may sound wasteful, but it's fine.

For example, with network requests it's common to fire a network request, and before it can return, fire a new request. You no longer need the first one, so you just need to dispose of it, and you can actually handle the request you wanted to respond to.

Answer (score 0):

Re-subscribing to the new list is certainly an option but that sounds too complex for a view logic. Try to keep views as simple as possible. All your view needs to do is just these two things:

- Subscribe to the filtered event list observable.
- Request a new event list

The filtered event list observable may emit only once, or multiple times. View shouldn't care how many time it emits new list. Instead of having multiple subscription logic in the view, you can abstract all your switching logic in the view model layer using `switchMap` and `BehaviorSubject`.

**ViewModel**

```
public class EventViewModel {

    private BehaviorSubject<Interval> interval = BehaviorSubject.create();

    // Let view to subscribe to the filtered event list.
    public Observable<List<Event>> getFilteredEvent() {
        return interval.switchMap(interval -> getAllByInterval(interval.startDate, interval.endDate));
    }

    // Let view to request new event list. Note that this method returns nothing.
    public void updateInterval(Date dateStart, Date dateEnd) {
        interval.onNext(new Interval(dateStart, dateEnd));
    }

    // Make this private.
    private Observable<List<Event>> getAllByInterval(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        ...
    }

    private static class Interval {
        final Date startDate;
        final Date endDate;

        Interval(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
            this.startDate = startDate;
            this.endDate = endDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `EventViewModel` has exactly two public methods. Each public method corresponds to each requirement defined above.

**View**

```
// Do this only once:
compositeDisposable.add(eventViewModel.getFilteredEvent().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
            (events, throwable) -> {
                if (throwable != null) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }

                if (events != null) {
                    // do funny things
                }
            }
    ));

// Do this as many times as you like. New list will be emitted
// by EventViewModel.getFilteredEvents.
eventViewModel.updateInterval(dateStart, dateEnd);
```

In case you are using `Flowable` instead of `Observable`, you can replace `BehaviorSubject` with `BehaviorProcessor`.